# Boolean help in c# How to format whether or not random1 matches num1

Tags: c#, regex, boolean

I was instructed to do this: 
"keep track of the matching status of each digit in a boolean check all three boolean match variables, if they are all true then we have a match to the winning number, exit out of the while loop"

I am 90% finished with this assignment but I'm not sure I understand how to use bool properly.

I'm assuming he wants me to check whether randomNum1 matches userEnteredNum1.

but I'm struggling to format it.

I started by doing this:

```
     bool doTheyMatch1 = true
```

but then I have no idea where to go from there. So I went to a more familiar "if" statement

```
    if (random1 = userEntered1stDigit)
```

and got the "cannot implicitly convert type int to bool" error. Any suggestions or helpful links are most welcome!

to be more helpful, here is my entire code:

```
       public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //DECLARE CLASS LEVEL FIELD VARIABLES
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick3 = 500;
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick4 = 5000;
    int CONST_cashPayoutPick5 = 50000;

    private void myBtnGenRandomNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
        int userEntered1stDigit = 0;
        int userEntered2ndDigit = 0;
        int userEntered3rdDigit = 0;


        //INPUT-VALIDATION
        //winning number: validate the 1st digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox1stDigit.Text, out userEntered1stDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the first box");
            return;
        }
        //winning number: validate the 2nd digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox2ndDigit.Text, out userEntered2ndDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the second box");
            return;
        }
        //winning number: validate the 3rd digit to be numeric, if not display error message and return
        if (int.TryParse(myTxtBox3rdDigit.Text, out userEntered3rdDigit))
        {
            //ok
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the third box");
            return;
        }


        //INITIALIZE ANY VARIABLES
        userEntered1stDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox1stDigit.Text);
        userEntered2ndDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox2ndDigit.Text);
        userEntered3rdDigit = int.Parse(myTxtBox3rdDigit.Text);

        //GOOD SO FAR

        //PROCESSING
        //setup your own Random number generator object
        int random1 = 0;
        int random2 = 0;
        int random3 = 0;

        Random myRandomNumberObject = new Random();
        int matchNum1;
        int matchNum2;
        int matchNum3;

        //clear the list box
        myListBoxResults.Items.Clear();

        //set number of attempts = 0
        int myAttemptsInt;
        myAttemptsInt = 0;


        //LOOP THROUGH AND CREATE SETS OF 3 RANDOM DIGITS EACH TIME THROUGH LOOP UNTIL A MATCH IS FOUND OR TRY 1,000 TIMES
        while (myAttemptsInt <= 1000) 
        {

            if (myAttemptsInt <= 999)
            {
                //ok
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 1
            random1 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);
            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 2
            random2 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);
            //get next random digit generated from 0 to 9, for your generated digit position 3
            random3 = myRandomNumberObject.Next(10);


            //display the number of match attempts so far

            //attempt # originally went here
            myAttemptsInt = myAttemptsInt + 1;

            int index = myListBoxResults.Items.Add("Attempt # " + myAttemptsInt);

            //display the generated digit 1,2,3 in the labels on the Form
            matchNum1 = random1;
            myLabelGenerated1stDigit.Text = matchNum1.ToString();
            matchNum2 = random2;
            myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.Text = matchNum2.ToString();
            matchNum3 = random3;
            myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.Text = matchNum3.ToString();

            //set the Label BackColor of all the generated digits to Color.LightGray
            myLabelGenerated1stDigit.BackColor= Color.LightGray;
            myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

            //for any generated digit that matches the winning digit,
            if (random1 == userEntered1stDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated1stDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
            if (random2 == userEntered2ndDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated2ndDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
            if (random3 == userEntered3rdDigit)
            {
                myLabelGenerated3rdDigit.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }

            //  -keep track of the matching status of each digit in a boolean
            bool doTheyMatch = true;
            if (random1 = userEntered1stDigit)

            //check all three boolean match variables, if they are all true then we have a match to the winning number, exit out of the while
            /*
            if (??)
            {
                //add what happened to the event log

                //break out of while loop since found a match
                break;
                //
            }
            else
            {
                //add what happened to the event log

                //no need to break out of loop; keep looping
            }
            */

        }  // End of While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, change `=` with `==`

In any C flavour, `=` assigns and returns the assigned value, `==` does a boolean operation and returns `true` or `false`

Also, you can avoid the if doing

```
bool theyMatch = (numberOne == numberTwo) && (numberThree == numberFour) && (numberFive == numberSix);
```

Also, when you are testing a `bool`, you don't need to compare with true because it's already a `bool`

```
if(theyMatch == true)
{
   //your code
}

//Behaves the same as 

if(theyMatch)
{

   //Your code

}
```

Comment: I changed bool doTheyMatch1 == true but.. It doesn't DO anything, I don't know how to tell it what to do is my problem. I have no grasp of boolean expressions. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Nope, change it in  if (random1 = userEntered1stDigit)

Comment: oh duh.. lol ok done, it fixed the if error! Now how would I use the if statement to "keep track of whether or not the numbers match"?

Comment: you are amazing! I think that is much closer to what he needs us to do, and no errors. Thank you!! I'm currently adjusting to my code

Comment: then would I say: if (theyMatch == true) {messagebox success break loop etc} and move on?

Comment: Yes, also you can do if(theyMatch)..., "==" yields a boolean, if you are checking already a boolean it's not necessary to compare it.

Comment: hmm so I can say theyMatch == true {instructions here} without the IF since I now have a boolean already?

Comment: lol, no, you can skip the "== true" part, I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: OH I understand now!! I am taking the next c# ON campus -_- I hate being new lol Thank you so so much for your patience! A lot of people here are more advanced, they can get a bit sarcastic lol

Comment: Don't worry, all of us at some point where newbies to programming ;)

Comment: Hopefully I get past the new stage quickly, I work hard, but I think this is something I need to be on campus for, to ask the silly questions right then and there. My degree will end up being software development. It seems far away considering I'm still figuring out booleans lol Thank you again, I appreciate the help!